# NextJS Typescript - Setup tslint configuration to force error when have unused import/declarations

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, lint, tslint

can anyone tell me how to force error when I have an unused import/declaration written in next typescript?

the use case is:
example I have
`import { Accordion, AccordionButton } from '@chakra-ui/react';`
the Accordion component is *used*, but for AccordionButton is **unused**, I want when I save the file I got an error compile cause of AccordionButton is not used.

Note:
I already add:
`"noUnusedLocals": true, "noUnusedParameters": true`

in tsconfig.json but still not resolved my problem

Answer (score 0):

It can very much depend on the editor you use. In VScode I have it set up to grey out unused imports so you can easily notice and remove them.

In your VScode config:

```
{
  "javascript.validate.enable": true,
  "editor.showUnused": true
}
```

As far as getting an error, there is an eslint plugin which can show a linting error for unused imports here:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-unused-imports